# missing spell effect on hand leads to crash

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

The spell effect goes missing from time to time.
It is missing in 1st and 3rd person.
It seems to happen with any spell.

When this happens, I know the game will crash but only if:

- I have no hands with the spell that has missing effect (I can have both hands with it, but as soon I have none, like equipping a 2handed, the game crashes).
- I quit to main screen.
- I try to load a game.

My game is heavily moded on PC.
I have started a new game.
I have used TES5Edit to create a merged patch.

Papyrus shows nothing special on logs.

```
[Papyrus]
bEnableLogging=1
bEnableTrace=1
bLoadDebugInformation=1
```

SKSE ini should be fixing most problems.

```
[General]
ClearInvalidRegistrations=1
```

I also use [ENBoost](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/38649), so my initial guess it is not graphics related.

What would you do to try to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Well... since your question boils down to "What would you do to try to solve this?" the answer would be:

1. Backup your save data and keep them safe somewhere
2. Start a new game with no mods active. This is the clean, vanilla save you'll use frequently, so back it up too
3. Activate all the mods you use in the troublesome game, if one of them is the culprit the problem should also appear in your new game
4. If it does appear, try to turn off your mods binary-search-style:

   - Turn off half of your mods and load the clean save. If the problem appears, then the culprit is somewhere between the active half, if not then the culprit is somewhere between the non-active half
   - Repeat the above step with the half where the culprit is, until you pin it down to the problematic one
5. Deal with the culprit

Sometimes the problem is not because of a particular mod, but rather because of the way it interacts with another mod, causing conflict. In this case you'll need to turn off your mods one by one and load the clean save to find out which mods that potentially cause problems

Comment: I think step 3 is what ClearInvalidRegistrations does in a sense that any failing scripts stored on the savegame gets removed. I have been postponing similar troublesome approach for a long time.. I will report back when I get to it, thx :)

Comment: I've never tried the SKSE's approach. Last I heard, the devs said that any script introduced by a mod stays in the save game forever, there is no save-cleaning mechanism like the previous games. Still, I recommend the manual approach because any attempt to clean the troublesome save might mask the problem: conflict between mods

Comment: you should try ClearInvalidRegistrations, is much less troublesome for usual problems :) (mine is unusual lol)

Comment: I haven't followed the Skyrim modding scene for about a year now. Last time I was active the feature was still just released and people were still testing it. I'll give it a try when I come back to Skyrim modding :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 7 years late but if anyone stumbles upon this problem, try this

Fallrim Tools:

Remember when you come to the saving step go to Files then, "save as" click on the save you are cleaning and just change the number of the save in the file name
(eg. Save75_160A7568_0_426561_Tamriel_030606_20220101102659_33_1.ess to Save76_160A7568_0_426561_Tamriel_030606_20220101102659_33_1.ess)

Also make note you can never completely clean a save if these does not help then the save is unredeemable( not because of the steps also your save will be like the above examble no. 75 )

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/5031 - SSE

https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/76776 - LE

Sorry if this does not help.